# Stack Exchange Global Types - a type declaration package for global objects exposed by Stack Exchange

Tags: library, typescript

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image: animated usage example]

### About

Stack Exchange global types is a type declaration package adding or augmenting type definitions for global objects exposed by Stack Exchange for client-side consumption on pages of network sites. Currently, the package includes the `StackExchange`, `StackOverflow`, `CHAT`, `Svg`, and `Stacks` global object definitions.

### Change log

Please note that the major version 2 starts from the patch version 2.0.2 due to the technical difficulties we encountered when bumping the major version.

| Since | Feature | Definitions/augmentations | Known Limitations |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [1.0.0](https://github.com/userscripters/stackexchange-global-types/releases/tag/v1.0.0) | augments `Stacks` exposed by the [@stackoverflow/stacks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@stackoverflow/stacks) package | Adds missing classes and helper methods like `showModal`/`hideModal` (see [example usage](https://stackoverflow.design/product/components/modals/#helpers) in official Stacks docs) |  |
| [1.1.0](https://github.com/userscripters/stackexchange-global-types/releases/tag/v1.1.0) | adds type definitions for `StackExchange` object (exposed on all pages on the network sites) | Full definition (for example, `StackExchange.options.user.isRegistered`) - as most of the Stack Exchange codebase is not open-source, so there are no type definitions available to augment | v1.1.1 only includes some of the exposed helper methods as each needs to be tested |
| [1.2.0](https://github.com/userscripters/stackexchange-global-types/releases/tag/v1.2.0) | adds type definitions for the `CHAT` object | Full definition (for example, `CHAT.user.canModerate()`) |  |
| [1.2.1](https://github.com/userscripters/stackexchange-global-types/releases/tag/v1.2.1) | adds `question` nested object to `StackExchange` global object | Three new method definitions: `getQuestionId()`, `canViewVoteCounts()`, `scrollToPost(postId)` | `getQuestionId` throws an error on non-post pages, but that's not expressable via declarations |
| 1.2.2 | type docs & improvements | Courtesy of [double-beep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10607772/double-beep): documentation for types and stricter `AllPlacements` |  |
| [1.3.0](https://github.com/userscripters/stackexchange-global-types/releases/tag/v1.3.0) | adds `settings` object for `StackExchange` object | Partial definition - adds account, flagging, markdown, and site-wide settings definitions |  |
| [1.4.0](https://github.com/userscripters/stackexchange-global-types/releases/tag/v1.4.0) | more type definitions for the `CHAT` global object courtesy of [double-beep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10607772/double-beep) | Full definition for `UserInformation`, `RoomUsersInfo`, and several methods |  |
| [1.5.0](https://github.com/userscripters/stackexchange-global-types/releases/tag/v1.5.0) | methods on `StackExchange` global object | adds `ready` and `gaReady` defer methods |  |
| [2.0.2](https://github.com/userscripters/stackexchange-global-types/releases/tag/v2.0.2) | `Stacks` namespace declaration merging; package splitting | Merges `Stacks` declaration with official TypeScript source; splits the declarations into 3 submodules: `chat`, `stackexchange`, and `stacks` (can be imported directly as `@userscripters/stackexchange-global-types/lib/<module>` if you only need some of the global types or as a bundle if you import the package with `@userscripters/stackexchange-global-types`) |  |
| [2.1.0](https://github.com/userscripters/stackexchange-global-types/releases/tag/v2.1.0) | adds type definitions for the `Svg` object | Full definition of all 228 icon helpers courtesy of [double-beep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10607772/double-beep) |  |
| [2.1.1](https://github.com/userscripters/stackexchange-global-types/releases/tag/v2.1.1) | improved `Stacks` definitions | `ModalController` defintion & tests |  |
| [2.2.0](https://github.com/userscripters/stackexchange-global-types/releases/tag/v2.2.0) | new testing framework | switched to [tsd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsd) for testing - please upgrade if you see a "Patch file found for package definitelytyped-header-parser" error when installing the package |  |
| [2.3.0](https://github.com/userscripters/stackexchange-global-types/releases/tag/v2.3.0) | adds type definitions for the `StackOverflow` object | Full definition of all enums |  |
| [2.4.0](https://github.com/userscripters/stackexchange-global-types/releases/tag/v2.4.0) | adds `realtime` property and corresponding `Realtime` interface on the global `StackExchange` object | Full definition of all properties and methods |  |
| [2.4.1](https://github.com/userscripters/stackexchange-global-types/releases/tag/v2.4.1) | adds Stimulus `application` singleton and controller utilities to the `Stacks` namespace | Courtesy of [Martijn Pieters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters): `ControllerDefinition` interface, `createController` and `addController` utilities, `application` singleton |  |
| [2.4.2](https://github.com/userscripters/stackexchange-global-types/releases/tag/v2.4.2) | adds missing `StackExchange.helpers` defintions | added `addLightbox`, `bindMovablePopups`, `showBannerMessage`, `showErrorMessage`, `showInfoMessage`, and `showSuccessMessage` helpers |  |
| [2.5.2](https://github.com/userscripters/stackexchange-global-types/releases/tag/v2.5.2) | adds missing `StackExchange.vote` definitions; updates SVG types; adds missing helpers | Full definition of all properties and methods; `htmlEncode` helper and `useRawHtml` option |  |
| [2.6.0](https://github.com/userscripters/stackexchange-global-types/releases/tag/v2.6.0) | adds all remaining `StackExchange.helpers` definitions; updates SVG types | Full definition of every helper |  |
| [2.7.0](https://github.com/userscripters/stackexchange-global-types/releases/tag/v2.7.0) | adds more properties of the `StackExchange` global object | Courtesy of [Martijn Pieters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters): Stacks declarations now use official typings. interfaces: `CommentsSettings`, `ElectionsSettings`, `IntercomSettings`, `LegalSettings`, `MentionsSettings`, `PathsSettings`, `QuestionsSettings`, `SnippetsSettings`, `SubscriptionsSettings`, `TopBarSettings`, `VoteBountyInitOptions`. more `settings` properties. properties: `sidebar`, `snippets`, `vote_bounty`, `vote_closingAndFlagging`. |  |

#### License

The script is licensed under the [GPL-3.0-or-later](https://spdx.org/licenses/GPL-3.0-or-later) license.

#### Download

The package is published as both an [NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@userscripters/stackexchange-global-types) and a [GitHub package](https://github.com/userscripters/stackexchange-global-types/packages/922352). Can be installed via a package manager like NPM as usual:

```shell
npm install --save-dev @userscripters/stackexchange-global-types
```

If you opt to install it from the GitHub registry, please note that it only supports scoped packages, you will need a simple .npmrc file at your project root:

```
@userscripters:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com
```

You will also need to be logged in to GitHub. An easy way to do so is to have a global `.npmrc` with your PAT ([personal access token](https://spdx.org/licenses/GPL-3.0-or-later)) set as an access token:

```
//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=<your token here>
```

#### Platform

The type declarations are intended to be used with TypeScript/JavaScript projects targeting browsers.

### Contact

Author: [Oleg Valter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11407695/oleg-valter)
Organization: [UserScripters](https://github.com/userscripters)

Contributors (core):
[double-beep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10607772/double-beep) (with special thanks for initial definitions and docs)

Contributors:
[Martijn Pieters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters)

Please, submit bug reports on the [source repository](https://github.com/userscripters/stackexchange-global-types/issues).
Before adding a new one, please check if it hasn't been raised before.

You can also [drop by to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214345/userscript-newbies-and-friends), we are a friendly bunch.

### Code

[Source code](https://github.com/userscripters/stackexchange-global-types/blob/master/index.d.ts) is written TypeScript (`d.ts` declaration files).

The project is using `tsd` (see [repo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsd)) for unit-testing types.

Contributions are welcome, you can always submit a [PR here](https://github.com/userscripters/stackexchange-global-types/pulls).